# Firebase - Is Data Persisted When a User Signs Out?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have enabled offline support in my app using:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

I am using only Google Sign In for authentication.

I was wondering that **when a user signs out, does the data related to the user remain persisted in the local sqlite database?**

If No, then how can I ensure that it remains persisted as I wouldn't want the user to download stuff again when he signs back again.

Comment: What user details you want to persist?

Comment: I am building a chat app like WhatsApp , so in that case all chats.

Comment: Yes, it would cache it locally and in case of no internet it would store and send automatically when connectivity is restored

Comment: Thanks, do the images downloaded & placed in local folder also remain cached?

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath sounds like an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void setPersistenceEnabled(boolean isEnabled)
```

By default the Firebase client will keep data in memory while your application is running, but not when it is restarted. By setting this value to `true`, the data will be persisted to on-device (disk) storage and will thus be available again when the app is restarted (even when there is no network connectivity at that time

isEnabled - Set to true to enable disk persistence, set to false to disable it.

Comment: More info - https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/Config.html#setPersistenceEnabled-boolean-